# pandas and csv how to create csv as a string without saving

Tags: python, pandas

I know how to save a DF as a csv file.  I want the csv as a string and I dont want to have to save, then load.

```
df.to_csv('test.csv',index=True)
my_csv = open('test.csv').read()
print type(my_csv)
<type 'str'>
```

Rather I would rater do the below:

```
my_csv = df.to_csv()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) module:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(3), 'b':list('abc')})
>>> s = StringIO()
>>> df.to_csv(s)
>>> my_csv = s.getvalue()
>>> my_csv
',a,b\n0,0,a\n1,1,b\n2,2,c\n'
```